# How to Get Uploaded File Name with glob() Function?

Tags: php, filenames, glob

I have a form for users to upload files into the folder.
HTML and PHP codes are as below:

```html
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="test.php">
  <input type="text" name="name"/><br/>
  <input type="file" name="photo" /><br/>
  <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

```
<?php  //test.php
    move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"], "testFolder/".$_POST["name"]);
?>
```

The upload form works well, and uploaded files are in the folder **testFolder/** .

Now I want to use **glob()** function to get all file names in the folder.

```
<?php
  foreach(glob("testFolder/*.*") as $file) {
    echo $file."<br/>";
  }
?>
```

However, it doesn't echo anything.

The glob() function works well on other folders, which contains existing files, not uploaded files.

But why doesn't it work on this folder with uploaded files ?

Comment: First thing you always do is this: take a look into your http servers error log file.

Comment: Check the path of your folder where you are using `glob()`

Comment: @arkascha How could I find my http servers error log file ?
I'm using Apache server.

Comment: Take a look into your http server configuration. You are looking for the `ErrorLog` directive. Standard configuration is something like `/var/log/apache2/...`.

Comment: @arkascha 

My Error log doesn't  shows anything related to the file with glob().
But the access log reads:
::1 - - [30/Jun/2017:18:20:40 +0800] "GET /test.php HTTP/1.1" 200 -

Does it mean anything ?

Comment: That looks fine, it is a standard request to the object `/test.php` which succeeded (http status 200: "ok")

Comment: Since I assume that the `glob()` function is called in _another_ script: there are no entries in the access log file to _that_ script? Please make sure you are not looking at cached results in your browser: disable/clear your browsers cache or make a "deep reload".

Comment: @arkascha It still doesn't work after clearing the browsers cache.
I guess whether it is related to my authority to access the uploaded file? I found that I am not able to open uploaded files from the folder. I can only reach the file with browser. For example: localhost/testFolder/abc

Comment: That is perfectly ok: since the file has been created by the http server process it is that process (user account) that owns the file. Certainly then that file should be able to again access such files, other accounts not necessarily. I suggest you find out the exact ownership and permissions of these files. What does a `ls -al ......./testFolder` give? Please add that information to the question above, there is an `edit` link below it.

Comment: @arkascha I just solved the problem!!! Because I didn't give the uploaded file an extension while using move_uploaded_file(). That's why glob("testFolder/*.*") doesn't gets anything. Should I just answer myself here? (I'm new on Stack Overflow here...)

Comment: Sure, go ahead. Write an answer yourself.

Comment: @arkascha Thank you ! Nice to discuss with you !  =")

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because I didn't give the extension for the uploaded file, that's why `glob("testFolder/*.*")` doesn't get anything.

Two solutions:

1. Give uploaded files an extension.

> $ext  = strrchr($_FILES["photo"]["name"], ".");
>
> move_uploaded_file($_FILES["photo"]["tmp_name"],
>   "testFolder/".$_POST["name"].$ext);

Then, `glob("testFolder/*.*")` will be able to get these uploaded files with an extension.

2. Just change `glob("testFolder/*.*")` to be `glob("testFolder/*")`

Answer (score 0):

*Possbile wildcard extension could be the issue.*

It may be that glob does not allow wildcard extensions, i dont see any mention of this in the docs. Have you tried a directory iterator?

```
$dir = new DirectoryIterator(__DIR__.'/testFolder);
foreach ($dir as $file) {
    echo $file->getFilename();
}
```

---

**UPDATE: THE PATH IS NOT THE ISSUE**

You are using a relative file path, therefore glob probably isn't finding the directory you are trying to search for.

Either the script calling the function needs to sit inside the parent directory of '**testFolder**' or you need to use an absolute path like so.

```
<?php
  foreach(glob("/absolute/path/to/testFolder/*.*") as $file) {
    echo $file."<br/>";
  }
?>
```

If you do want to use a relative path you  could do the following:

```
<?php
  //__DIR__ is a PHP super constant that will get the absolute directory path of the script being ran

  // .. = relative, go up a folder level

  foreach(glob(__DIR__."/../testFolder/*.*") as $file) {
    echo $file."<br/>";
  }
?>
```

Obviously the paths above are examples but should get you on the right track.

Hope this helps

Comment: Then why does the `move_uploaded_file()` call succeed using the same relative path?

Comment: I think it has nothing to do with the relative path.
I tried glob($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']."/testFolder/*.*")
But it doesn't work either....

Comment: @EdChen It might, if your two scripts are in different folders.

Comment: The the path is _not_ the issue, agreed. So back to the comments to the question...

Comment: Can you use an extension as a wildcard with glob? I cant see any mention of it. Maybe you need the DirectoryIterator class

Comment: @Goon3r Thanks for your answer. I just found the answer. The glob() doesn't work because my uploaded files don't have extension.